# Expand/Collapse shiny box on header click

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have developed a shiny app, where we are using various box object in the ui. Currently the boxes expand/Collapse by clicking on the "+/-" sign on the right of the box header, but we need the expand/collapse on click on the header (anywhere on the box header). 
Below code (sample code)
If you look at the box with chart, I want the expansion & collapse to be performed on clicking the header i.e. "Histogram box title" and not just the "+/-" sign on right side of the header:

```
    ## Only run this example in interactive R sessions
    if (interactive()) {
      library(shiny)

      # A dashboard body with a row of infoBoxes and valueBoxes, and two rows of boxes
      body <- dashboardBody(
        # Boxes
        fluidRow(
          box(title = "Histogram box title",
              status = "warning", solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = TRUE,
              plotOutput("plot", height = 250)
          )
        )


      )

      server <- function(input, output) {

        output$plot <- renderPlot({
          hist(rnorm(50))
        })
      }

      shinyApp(
        ui = dashboardPage(
          dashboardHeader(),
          dashboardSidebar(),
          body
        ),
        server = server
      )
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is easily achievable using javascript. You just have to create a javascript function and call the same in your header code. Refer to below code for better understanding. I have provided 3 options, let me know if this works for you.

```
## Only run this example in interactive R sessions
if (interactive()) {
  library(shiny)

# javascript code to collapse box
jscode <- "
shinyjs.collapse = function(boxid) {
$('#' + boxid).closest('.box').find('[data-widget=collapse]').click();
}
"

  # A dashboard body with a row of infoBoxes and valueBoxes, and two rows of boxes
  body <- dashboardBody(
    # Including Javascript
    useShinyjs(),
    extendShinyjs(text = jscode),
    # Boxes
    fluidRow(
      box(id="box1",title = actionLink("titleId", "Histogram box title",icon =icon("arrow-circle-up")), 
          status = "warning", solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = T,
          plotOutput("plot", height = 250)
      ),
      box(id="box2",title = p("Histogram box title", 
                          actionButton("titleBtId", "", icon = icon("arrow-circle-up"),
                                       class = "btn-xs", title = "Update")), 
          status = "warning", solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = T,
          plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)
      ),
      box(id="box3",title = actionButton("titleboxId", "Histogram box title",icon =icon("arrow-circle-up")), 
          status = "warning", solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = T,
          plotOutput("plot2", height = 250)
      )
    )


  )

  server <- function(input, output) {

    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      hist(rnorm(50))
    })
    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
      hist(rnorm(50))
    })
    output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
      hist(rnorm(50))
    })

    observeEvent(input$titleId, {
      js$collapse("box1")
    })
    observeEvent(input$titleBtId, {
      js$collapse("box2")
    })
    observeEvent(input$titleboxId, {
      js$collapse("box3")
    })
  }

  shinyApp(
    ui = dashboardPage(
      dashboardHeader(),
      dashboardSidebar(),
      body
    ),
    server = server
  )
}
```

Comment: firstly, thanks for your reply, this surely helped. But it is behaving bit strangely. In my app, I have 2 main boxes in the sidebarPanel, and each of these boxes have 3 sub boxes, which contains different inputs. The applied your example 1 on all of my boxes, it is working fine for the first main box and its respective sub boxes, but it is not working for the second main box and its sub boxes. I have checked everything, the code appears to be fine everywhere. Do you have any idea as how it can happen?
I can't share my original code here, but will try putting a similar example.

Comment: Glad it was helpful...!! Regarding your new issue that the code is working for one main box only... All I can suggest right now that please perform a cross check on below two things:- 1) If you have included ShinyJS properly. 2) If all box ids are different....If it still does not work please create a reusable example...

Comment: Also, If it has solved your purpose...Please accept/upvote the answer to help others with the solution..

Comment: Sir, you were right, I messed up with IDs, I have corrected it and it is working perfectly fine. Thanks again.
I have already upvoted the answer, but as I am new to stackOverflow and doesn't the required reputation score, it is not reflecting  above.
But Thanks a ton.

Comment: Glad I could help...!! Since this was your question, you can accept the answer. You simply need to mark an answer as correct ( click on the green check image). Refer to this link for clarification (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow)

Comment: In the newer version of Shinyjs you need to add the function parameter to extendShinyjs(). Use: extendShinyjs(text = jscode, functions = c("collapse"))

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for all boxes in an app with a few lines of external css and javascript.

The JS triggers a click on the widget when you click on the header title. It has to be the h3 element because the widget is inside .box-header, which would cause infinite recursion.

```
$('.box').on('click', '.box-header h3', function() {
    $(this).closest('.box')
           .find('[data-widget=collapse]')
           .click();
});
```

But then we need to make the h3 element fill the full .box-header, so get rid of the header padding (except on the right), add it to the h3, and make the h3 fill 100% of the width of the box.

```
.box-header {
  padding: 0 10px 0 0;
}
.box-header h3 {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Lisa DeBruine answer is the better one since you can click the whole header and not just the title.

Pasted it into a small example:

```
if (interactive()) {
  body <- dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    
      tags$style(HTML("
      .box-header {
        padding: 0 10px 0 0;
      }
      .box-header h3 {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px;
      }")),
    
      fluidRow(
        box(id="box1", title = "Histogram box title",
            status = "warning", solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = T,
            plotOutput("plot", height = 250)
        )
      )
    )
  
    server <- function(input, output) {
    
      output$plot <- renderPlot({
        hist(rnorm(50))
      })
    
      runjs("
      $('.box').on('click', '.box-header h3', function() {
          $(this).closest('.box')
                 .find('[data-widget=collapse]')
                 .click();
      });")
    }
  
  shinyApp(
    ui = dashboardPage(
      dashboardHeader(),
      dashboardSidebar(),
      body
    ),
    server = server
  )
}
```